# How to send data in a post request with RestClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, curl, rest-client

I'm trying to mimic a curl request using the RestClient Ruby gem, and so far, I've been having a lot of trouble trying to send in a payload.  My curl request looks something like this

`curl URL -X POST -u API_KEY -d '{"param_1": "1"}'`

I've been trying to replicate this with RestClient using something like this:

`RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: URL, user: API_KEY, payload: {"param_1" => "1"})`

Alas, I keep getting 400 - Bad Requests errors when doing this.  Am I sending data over the wrong way?  Should I be using something other than payload?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change:

```
payload: {"param_1" => "1"})
```

To:

```
payload: '{"param_1": "1"})'
```

Also, specify the `headers`.

So, it becomes:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                            url: 'your_url',
                            user: 'API_KEY',
                            payload: '{"param_1": "1"}',
                            headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
                           )
```

Comment: Everything is working fine with cURL.  I'm curious how I'd make the equivalent query with RestClient

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Ultimately, I had to pass in an argument to clarify that my data was being sent over in JSON.

Comment: Yes, you had another issue that your `payload` was not a string, it was a hash. My answer addressed that issue. Also, if it did not work, then I would tell you to add the `headers` option to the request. But you already did that, which is great :)

Comment: I think you have to switch payload: '{"param_1" => "1"}' to payload: '{"param_1" : "1"}'.  If you change that, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93275/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-rboling).

Comment: Although those two are the same, using just different hash syntax and both should work,
but I changed to `payload: '{"param_1" : "1"}'` which is the latest ruby hash syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Just Change:

```
payload: {"param_1" => "1"}
```

To:

```
payload: {"param_1" => "1"}.to_json
```

So, then it becomes:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                            url: 'your_url',
                            user: 'API_KEY',
                            payload: {"param_1" => "1"}.to_json,
                            headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
                           )
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to add an argument to specify that my data was in a JSON format.  The correct answer was something like this:
`RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: URL, user: API_KEY, payload: '{"param_1": "1"}', headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"})`

Comment: you could have check-marked the @K M Rakibul Islam's answer; Rboling